# Is directly assigning value to variables safe in C?

Tags: c, variables

Is directly assigning value to variables safe in C?

I think that first I should declare a variable and then use like this:
 `int v;
v = 56;`

But directly assigning the variable like this doesn't give any errors:

`int v = 56;`

Is it safe to directly assign values to a variable like `int v = 56?`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a well defined feature call *initialization*. For variables declared outside of a function (and static variables) the value is also typically compiled into the object code so there is no runtime cost associated with the initialization. In this case the initializer must also be a constant expression, that is an expression which can be evaluated when the program is compiled, so it cannot contain function calls (only macros).

Answer (score 0):

> int v=56;

Yes, this code is safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is right way. It is called initialization of a variable. You can refer following link.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-initialize-a-variable-in-c-c/

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's completely safe, there are the same thing, it gets compiled into the same thing.(GNU Assembly, compiled with gcc 9.3, no flags)

```
//int v = 56
movl    $56, -8(%rbp)
//int x = 65
movl    $65, -4(%rbp)
```

Declaring a variable is just letting the compiler know that there's a variable and it needs some space in the stack, so the compiler will reserve the space in the stack. So, it's the same! A good feature.

Comment: While you're correct it's safe, the fact that it did get compiled to the same thing in your specific case does not say anything.

Comment: @klutt No, it does mean it's safe because if you know one thing is safe and the other thing gets compiled into the same thing, then you know that the other thing is safe as well. This clearly shows runtime safety, but not compile time.

Comment: No, it does not mean that. Because you have no guarantee that they will be compiled to the same thing. It just happened to be that case in this case with your compiler with a specific version and compiler flags.

Comment: @klutt Oh I get your point. You're kinda, right it may be different in different situations. But it being the same on atleast mine may not be a solid proof, but is a liquid proof but is better than gas proof.

Comment: It's not even a liquid proof. I have seen lots of examples where code that invokes UB compiles to the same assembly as code that does not invoke UB.

Comment: I don't have any at hand this particular moment. But is it that surprising? If the code invokes UB, the standard imposes no requirements whatsoever on the compiler.

Comment: I found one example. `int main(void) {
    int *i = malloc(11);
    i[10] = 5;
    printf("%d", i[10]);
}`

If you change the argument for malloc to `0` instead of `11`, and use `-O3` on gcc version 9.3.1 it will generate the exact same binary. But the code is different, and more important, one invokes UB and one does not.